# Sorting Query in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Hi I am trying to sort my query.

```
    $time = fetchTimesPlay($edit_uuid);
    $time_records = array();
    $time_records = sizeof($time);
    for($x=0;$x<$time_records;$x++){

        $max = sizeof($time[$x])/2;
        for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++){
            unset($time[$x][$i]);
        }
    }
    $dbResult[0]['times'] = $time;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use PHPs [`usort`](http://ch1.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php).

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't sorting this on the database level?